# Why my Flash button disappears (Flash Pro.)?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4, flash-cs5

I'm following this tutorial on Flash Pro CS4:

http://www.baycongroup.com/flashCS4/09_flashCS4.html

I have a button. I pressed CTRL + E in this button, I clicked the 'hit' frame on the 'Text' layer and I created a new frame going in 'Insert > Timeline > frame' as said in the turorial. Like ins the image below.[image]

But after I create a new Frame(F5), as said in the tutorial, the button disappears, like the image below.
[image]

So, what I'm doing wrong? 
( Btw, is this kind of question allowed in SO? This is not exactly a source code question, but in the FAQ it's written that 'software tools commonly used by programmers' questions are also allowed. I don't know if Flash Professional would be a tool commonly used by **programmers** but I thought wouldn't hurt asking.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend `State` layer as well. Just like what you did on the `Text` layer.

To do that, click on the `State` layer, go to `Hit`, and simply press F5. That's the quickest way to do it.